# Why does my email have no content in Rails 2.2, and only has an attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am trying to create an email from a template, and then also attach a .csv file to my email, however the email only comes through with the attachment and the content is ignored?  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
  def send_email(csv_file, results)
    @subject = "subject here"
    @from = "hl7_data mailer<hl7-data@email.com>"
    @recipients = HL7_DATA_EMAIL_ADDRESS
    @results = results
    attachment :content_type => "text/csv", :body => csv_file
  end

mailer_view/send_email.html.erb:
    Here is my content for the hl7 data email file: <%=@results%>
```

My file content used to display correctly but once I attached a file, it stopped displaying?

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I was looking for:

```
content = "here is my content"
part :content_type => "text/plain", :charset => "us-ascii", :body => cont
attachment :filename => 'invalid-records.csv', :disposition => "attachment", :content_type => "text/csv", :body => csv_file
```

So basically, I coulndt use the existing view file, I had to create inline content:
    `mailer_view/send_email.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

To send attachments, you have to change the @content_type:

```
@content_type = "multipart/mixed"
```

This should then allow attachments.

Comment: This is the default content_type when you add an attachment.